# How to escape "]" in a description's item tag?

Tags: brackets, description, grouping

In a description like

```
\begin{description}
\item[\texttt{DoSomething(items[])}:]
...
\end{description}
```

, how do I escape the "]" character?

Comment: I was obviously having some kind of meltdown here, I was reading [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) even as I was suggesting `\[\]`. I blame the lack of coffee.

Comment: In this particular case you don't need any special precaution, of course, since the `]` is already protected by braces. In general `\item[...{...[]...}...]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Group only the brackets or the whole expression with additional curly braces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item[\texttt{DoSomething(items{[]})}:]
    \item[{\texttt{DoSomethingElse(items[])}:}]
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer which I would have posted as well. I therefore undeleted it.

Comment: The reason a `]` breaks and adding `{ }` works is that optional arguments are not handled like normal ones (which can be cascaded) but are read as part of a macros parameter text from the `[` to the very next `]`. Placing the `]` inside `{ }` effectively hides it from TeX token scanner which is forced to obey the group. Note that macros defined with `xparse` handle cascaded `[ ]` correctly (through some extra effort done by that package).

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. I wasn't sure since `\item[\texttt{DoSomething(items[])}:]` works as is and doesn't need grouping. Additional braces are only necessary when writing `\item[{DoSomething(items[]):}]`.

Comment: @Thorsten: Any braces around `]` will do. It doesn't matter if they are part of a macro argument or not.